# wxGrid Scroll method

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there anyway to set the grid position using a function other than Scroll.
Scroll function won't do anything if Grid Scrollbars are set to to wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER.

```
import  wx
import  wx.grid as  gridlib
grid = gridlib.Grid(parent, wx.ID_ANY)
grid.ShowScrollbars(wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER,wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER)
# now Scroll method won't work anymore and scrolling to certain position does nothing
grid.Scroll(100,100) # it does nothing anymore.
```

The same way there is grid.GetViewStart() method, is there anything or any turnaround to Scroll or something like grid.SetViewStart ...

thanks

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? you probably will need to implement the 'scrolling' yourself by changing the data in the cells, instead of trying to 'scroll' it... see the wxgrid examples for dealing with large tables (it's written for cases where you _do_ want scrollbars, but don't want to keep the whole table in memory, but it might help here).

Comment: this is exactly what I am trying to achieve. you can refer to my previous unanswered query herein http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970101/how-to-start-showing-from-a-specific-column

Answer (score 1):

I think using something like `MakeCellVisible()` may be a better choice, rather than the arbitrary `Scroll()`

Comment: In my application I need to put the grid at an exact position to synchronize it with another grid. MakeCellVisible method doesn't assure the later.